# Why does the UI become a fullscreen, when I add a fragment in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, fragment, arcore

I have created a new project with "Bottom Navigation Activity" as template. If I add a fragment in my fragment_home.xml file a white bar at the bottom appears and the android taskbar disappears.

Here is a screenshot and the code without the fragment:
[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

And here a screenshot with the fragment:
[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I want the green bar at the top and under this, the fragment.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `MainActivity.xml` or whatever activity is hosting the `FrameLayout`

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun I added the mobile_navigation.xml. But that is a auto-generated xml.

Comment: No this is not what I have asked for.. I asked for your Activity layout file.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun okay I added this. But it is also auto-generated. I changed nothing except the fragment_home.xml

Comment: Where is this `FrameLayout`? In your homeFragment?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun exactly